# KEY-COMMIT with POST;

Tags: oracle12c

KEY-COMMIT created in form trigger which has the following code written by someone

```
IF :SYSTEM.FORM_STATUS = 'CHANGED' THEN
  POST;
END IF;
```

Does anyone know about POST;  ?

Many many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I do, but I'm not sure I can express it better than the Forms Builder online help says it, which presumably you have already seen?

> Writes data in the form to the database, but does not perform a
> database commit. Oracle Forms first validates the form. If there are
> changes to post to the database, for each block in the form Oracle
> Forms writes deletes, inserts, and updates to the database.
>
> Any data
> that you post to the database is committed to the database by the next
> COMMIT_FORM that executes during the current Runform session.
> Alternatively, this data can be rolled back by the next CLEAR_FORM.

Comment: Tony, thanks for reply. I have been seached for a week, but have not read any explaination about it.  I try to read it. Thanks.